# How to boost speed for CI pipeline with bazel build and test？

Tags: bazel

My CI pipeline has *build* and *test* stage using `bazel`, when the pipeline runs, `bazel` do full rebuild for *build* and *test* everytime. I want to boost speed of the pipeline, is there any idea?

I think if `bazel` has some options for setting different output directory for *build* and *test*, then *build* and *test* stage not affect each other, so it no need do full rebuild then. So is there some options for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If your CI has a persistent disk, you can use `--disk_cache=/path/to/dir` to keep state, even after clean builds and Bazel server shutdowns.

There is also support for [remote caching](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/remote-caching.html) over HTTP via on-prem machines or cloud solutions like Google Cloud Storage.

For even faster builds, especially for very large builds, Bazel has the ability to send build actions to remote machines via [remote execution](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/remote-execution.html).